# unable to make tls1.2 connection via CLI

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

When I do `openssl s_client -CApath ~/cacert.pem -crlf -connect getcomposer.org:443 -servername getcomposer.org` I get the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=getcomposer.org
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=getcomposer.org
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3183 bytes and written 455 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 222874F43D8C5CD5C5EBCE9519D767FC0847D4BCE75261020AEDA2337E84CE87
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 4C7B19187830AF58A6D03B37163A5C2CEF3222F6BC048D569B122DF372DFCA4CB7FAA0103AAE0C87B5C008E0692C48AD
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1634183395
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
closed
```

I don't understand this error. I just got cacert.pem by doing `wget --no-check-certificate -O ~/cacert.pem https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem` and doing `vim ~cacert.pem` verifies that the newly created file is non-empty.

Comment: `openssl -CApath` must specify a _directory_ with each root cert in a separate file named by its subject hash. For one _file_ containing multiple certs, the format supplied by curl.se, **use `-CAfile`**. If you want to use `-CApath` for some reason, split the cacert.pem file into separate files and use `c_rehash` to rename them (or write your own code/script to do so). Note this did not prevent you from making the connection; `s_client` does not fail for cert errors, like real code usually does. This does not appear to be a programming or development issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the community seems to have accepted this as ontopic:

As I commented, to use in `openssl` commandline a 'bundle' file in the format supplied by `https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem` **you must use `-CAfile` not `-CApath`**.

`-CApath` works instead with a *directory* containing a separate file for each cert named by its subject hash, as described in `man 1 verify` on older versions or `man 1 openssl-verification-options` on 3.0 [also here on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-verification-options.html#CApath-dir) and which you can use `c_rehash` to help create if that is really wanted for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark, as I don't understand that openssl output much, but judging by the timing and the keywords 'openssl' and 'Lets Encrypt' this has a reasonably high chance of success.

On September 30, 2021 [Let's Encrypt's old Root Certificate has expired](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). This had a major implication that now they have started to use their own root cert which should be trusted by most devices. 'Most' part was troublesome as there are some devices alive which did not receive updates in years. So the people at Let's Encrypt found a way to still remain supported/trusted on those devices, just under one condition - [its openssl version must be 1.1.0+](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/openssl-client-compatibility-changes-for-let-s-encrypt-certificates/143816) (which is already 4+ years old). Another important detail is that this openssl version requirement also applies to systems that would have otherwise trusted LE's new cert.

So I've seen numerous people over October scrambling to get LE issued certificates to be trusted again by their systems and the answer was always as simple as: **Get your openssl / libopenssl updated to v1.1.0+**

Comment: No. The OpenSSL 1.0.x problem with LE only occurs if the server uses LE's 'compatibility' chain (bridging to the expired DST root, which never belonged to LE/ISRG, although they arranged to be signed by it), which the Q shows it does not; AND the truststore still contains that DST root, which the curl bundle does NOT since Sep. 30, before this Q; AND when it does happen it results in verify error 10 'cert expired' (shown in other Qs on this topic) NOT 20 'unable to get local issuer' as in this Q.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 those are very good points. So I agree that my suggestion will not solve this particular problem. Yet updating OpenSSL from 1.0.x era is still a good idea :)